# Searching for locked records or tables on FirebirdSQL

Tags: firebird

Is it possible to find which records on which table are locked by a specific statement, transaction or attachment on FirebirdSQL 2.5?

I'm getting some *Lock conflict on no wait transaction* error messages on some situations.
I'm trying to trace the problem looking for ACTIVE transactions and statements using MON$STATEMENTS, MON$TRANSACTIONS and MON%ATTACHMENTS. I know the exact sql statement from MON$STATEMENTS but on some cases it is a stored procedure execution that updates many tables. So, finding the actual locked record or table would make analysis easier.

Comment: add some logging into the SP so you would see which table update was the last ?  also, dunno, maybe FBTrace API lets you write a plugin that can do it

Comment: Lock conflict on no wait transaction can have different causes and it will be hard to pinpoint without at least something of a rough outline of the situation where/when it occurs. Consider asking your question on the firebird-support list instead. Finding locked records themselves is not possible in Firebird.

Comment: See also http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq109/

Comment: I kinda found the main problem using MON$CALL_STACK. Since it only shows active statements it led me to a slow running query inside one stored procedure, after some record updates. I'm still getting some lock conflicts on production server. But way less now.